# Reverse stack represented by pointer in C

Tags: c

I tried to reverse stack with the following function. It seems to work fine at first but later after two inputs, it starts to modify the original stack.

I'm thinking something might be wrong with my while condition, but I test-ran it and it works fine. Below is my code:

```
void push(StackNodePtr *topPtr, BizarreNumber_t info) {
  StackNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));

  if (newPtr != NULL) {
    newPtr->data = info;
    newPtr->nextPtr = *topPtr;
    *topPtr = newPtr;
  } else {  // no space available
    printf("%d is not inserted. Memory error!\n", info.num);
  }
}

BizarreNumber_t pop(StackNodePtr *topPtr) {
  StackNodePtr tmpPtr = *topPtr;
  BizarreNumber_t result = (*topPtr)->data;

  *topPtr = (*topPtr)->nextPtr;

  free(tmpPtr);

  return result;
}

StackNodePtr reverseStack(StackNodePtr currentPtr) {
  StackNodePtr newPtr = NULL;
  while (currentPtr != NULL) {
    push(&newPtr, pop(&currentPtr));
  }
  return newPtr;
}
```

I'm not sure if I need to include my definition for StackNode. thanks for any help and suggestions.

Comment: *I'm not sure if I need to include my definition for stacknode* Yes, please, And also for all other custom types you use.

Comment: reverseStack is a destructive operation.  Is that what you mean by modifying the original stack?